# How to insert a variable in href link in iPython markup

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I am using Ipython Notebook 2

I have a file name in variable which dynamically calculates the location and file name of file located in current directory, And I want to insert that variable in my markup to download it

*below is the code:*

```
  result_file ="Revenue_per_city"+start_date+"_"+end_date+".xlsx
```

*then my markup to download the file:*

```
 <a href= {{result_file}}> Click here to download the result</a>
```

but its not working as expected

Comment: There is a typo. Spelling of `href` in the code.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro thanks for the correction but this is not the probelm :)

Answer (score 4):

You can display HTML using tools from the `IPython.display` module:

- `HTML` is an object representing HTML as text
- `display` is a function that displays objects (like `print`, but for rich-media objects)

For example:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

# create a string template for the HTML snippet
link_t = "<a href='{href}'> Click here to download the result</a>"

result_file = "Revenue_per_city" + start_date + "_" + end_date + ".xlsx"

# create HTML object, using the string template
html = HTML(link_t.format(href=result_file))

# display the HTML object to put the link on the page:
display(html)
```